# $ \int_\gamma e^{\frac{1}{z^2-1}}\sin{(\pi z)}dz $ on a closed curve of index $N$ with respect to the point $1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Let $\gamma$ be a closed curve in the right half plane that has index $N$ with respect to the point $1$. Find
$$ \int_\gamma e^{\frac{1}{z^2-1}}\sin{(\pi z)}dz $$

This is a problem from an old qualifying exam and I have tried to compute the reside of the integrand at the point $1$ where it has an essential singularity, but could not make any progress.  I found the same question posted before at [How to compute the complex integral $\int_{\gamma} e^{\frac{1}{z^2 - 1}}\sin{\pi z} \, \mathrm dz$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178650/how-to-compute-the-complex-integral-int-gamma-e-frac1z2-1-sin-pi)
but I feel that it was not satisfactorily answered even there. Can someone please help?

Comment: What do we know about the index of $\gamma$ with respect to the point $-1$?

Comment: As far as I understand from the statement of the problem, it can be arbitrary.